# Is the return type of an expression always match the operands type?

Tags: c++, c, types

In C++ the operands used in an expression must be of the same type (and if they are not, one operand is promoted to match the other).

My question is: can I assume that the return type of any expression will always match the type of its operands, or is there's an exception to this rule? For example is there's such a case:

```
typeY typeYVar = typeXVar / typeXVar2;
```

Even though both operands are of `typeX`, I am assuming that this expression will return a `typeY` value.

**Note:** I am talking about primitive types.

---

***Edit:*** I am referring to the **final type of operands**, that is after a promotion (if any) is performed on them (whether the promotion is to make the type of operands the same, or because a char/short/etc. needs to be promoted to an int).

Comment: I believe it is often wrong (and different in C and in C++). AFAIK `(short)x/(short)y` is having an `int` division on C

Comment: Ternary operator is an exception. Unary `*` and `&` are exceptions. Then, you can overload operators.

Comment: I can always define `bar operator+(foo, foo)`, so no, it isn't guaranteed.

Comment: For [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) read [draft n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) if you don't want to pay for the standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza Can you overload an operator and use it only on primitive types?

Comment: You can't override existing operators for builtin types (except operator new, perhaps, but that's something special... )

Comment: @joseph_m No, that isn't allowed.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Mm, nothing clearer than straight up reading the standard.

Comment: But n3337 is the standard in practice. (except perhaps for very minor typos). ISO standards are on paper and costly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There may be a few minor differences between promotions in C and in C++, I'm not sure, but at worst, they do still mostly match up. C++ also promotes integer types smaller than `int` to `int` before performing any arithmetic operation, so an addition, subtraction, multiplication or division of two values of type `short` produces an `int` in either language.

Comment: IIRC, `(float)x/(float)y` was computed in `double` in older C standards (ANSI C).But that has changed (probably in C99).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An obvious counter-example is pointer addition and subtraction:

```
const char *p = "Hello, world!";
const char *q = p + 1; // operands of type const char * and int, neither is converted to the other
auto diff = q - p; // two operands of type const char *, result has type ptrdiff_t
```

Relational operators are another obvious counter-example:

```
auto cmp = 1.23 < 4.56; // two operands of type double, result has type bool (or int in C)
```

Comment: +1 for the logical operator example. Maybe I should have pointed out in my question that I was only talking about binary arithmetic operators (excluding `%`): (`+ - * /`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is definitely possible - for example, when you use expressions that require integral promotions:

```
char a = 'a', b = 'b';
int c = a + b; // Operator + promotes a and b to int
cout << typeid(a+b).name() << endl; // prints "i"
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/r12RB8)

Comment: Yes you are right, But I meant if the return type will be the same after the promotion is performed: "and if they are not, one operand is promoted to match the other".

Comment: @joseph_m But the types of a and b are equal, so if either were converted to the type of the other like you suggest in the question, that wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation of an expression is largely independent of the type of variable the result is stored in.

If we do

```
int x = 4;
int y = 3;
long long z;
z = x/y;
```

The result of the expression "x/y" is of type int (and a value of 1).   This value of 1 is then converted to be of type long long (yielding 1LL).

Neither x nor y are implicitly converted (or promoted) to be of type long long before doing the division.   The result of the division is converted in order to do the assignment.

Some operations do involve implicit conversion (e.g. if dividing two variables of different types, there are specific rules about how promotion occurs)